# How can you use ZK-proofs and public key signatures in this situation?

Tags: public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs, zero-knowledge

Let us say that we have 3 entities: an Issuer `I` , a user/prover `P` and a verifier `V`.

1. `V` trusts `I` but does not trust `u`
2. `u` wants to show that he respects some kind of property (eg. being over 18yo) to `V` without revealing their whole birth day
3. `V` possesses the data that `u` needs to convince `V`, eg. using a ZK-proof, but `V` would not trust such a proof because `u` could easily use a fake date

How would you design a protocol such that `V` is assured that the claim `u` makes is legitimate (that is, that claim was issued by `I`)?

A first idea would be to use both public key signature (so, `V` sends `u` a signature of its date, so that even if `u` decides to use a fake date, the cannot provide a correct signature for that) and ZK-proof so that `u` provides only the strictly required informations to `V`. `V` would then check that the ZK-proof is correct and that the private input fed into the ZK-circuit is signed by `I`.

Some clarifications after Geoffroy's comment:

4. the user `u` should be aware of what information `V` wants to know, so we can't just let `V` and `I` communicate cutting out the user
5. the user has one or more statements issued and signed by `I` and wants to convince `V` that a claim about a statement (eg. `u` wants to prove that he is 18yo, given a birth certificate/ID/passport signed by `I`) without revealing the entire statement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your setting is not clear to me: does the issuer know the data as well? Why can't he just tell V that P is over 18yo, if V trusts them? Should anything be hidden from the issuer? More generally, since you mention ZK proofs: what exactly do you want to hide? A generic non-hiding solution would be: P convinces I that he is 18yo (e.g. using his passport), and I issues a signature on the message "P is 18yo" which it hands to P. Then P can use this as a credential with V.

Comment: The issuer knows the data, but we want P to be aware and consent to what information is given to V, so you can't really just let V ask the issuer or the user is completely cut out. The idea is that I issues a (digital and signed) document that states P date of birth (as an example) and P wants to prove a claim on that statement (eg. P is 18yo) without revealing the day of birth, so the user hides his date of birth but still convinced the verifier that they are 18yo.

Answer (score 1):

What you want looks very similar to anonymous credentials. Constructions usually go as follows: the issuer will sign the attribute of P (e.g. "P is 18yo"), usually using a blind issuance protocol. Then, P can send to V a commitment to his attribute, together with a ZK proof that he holds a signature on the committed value. In your specific setting where there is a unique verifier, there exist dedicated solutions using algebraic MACs, see [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/516.pdf).